# Does VkSubpassdependencies only usefull for subpasses inside a renderpass?

Tags: vulkan

Does subpass only perform syncronization for subpasses whitin a single render pass does it also include previous renderpasses and upcomming renderpasses in before/after scope. If so, when should I use a pipeline barrier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to carefully read the specification for these things. Vulkan synchronization is not something you figure out as you go.

The scopes are formally specified:

> If `srcSubpass` is equal to `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`, the *first synchronization scope* includes commands that occur earlier in *submission order* than the `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` used to begin the *render pass instance*. Otherwise, the first set of commands includes all commands submitted as part of the subpass instance identified by `srcSubpass` and any load, store or multisample resolve operations on attachments used in `srcSubpass`. In either case, the first synchronization scope is limited to operations on the pipeline stages determined by the *source stage mask* specified by `srcStageMask`.

and there's similar wording for the *second synchronization scope*.

To understand this, you must already know and fully grasp all the nomenclature involved here, which is also specified.

In short though, `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` covers stuff outside render pass. That half of the dependency works virtually the same as `vkCmdPipelineBarrier`. And having specific `*Supbass`, then the half of the dependency is limited only to that particular subpass.

> If so, when should I use a pipeline barrier?

Whenever using subpass dependency is not possible or inconvenient. I.e. for dependencies between two computes, queue ownership transfers, one-off layout transitions, etc...

Comment: Ok I got it. So basically when jsut using multiple renderpasses using subpassdependencies will probably be good enough

Comment: @IcaroAmorim Whenever you can, always use the most specific sync primitive. I.e. subpass dependencies ≥ pipeline barriers ≥ semaphores ≥ fences.